# Extend lombok mapping

Tags: java, mapping, lombok

I use the Lombok framework to extend the Java Class that I map. Currently, I use this:

```
// @Mapper(config = BaseMapperConfig.class)
public interface MerchantsMapper {

    MerchantNewDTO toNewDTO(Merchants merchant);
}
```

Custom implementation:

```
public MerchantNewDTO toNewDTO(Merchants merchant)
  {
    MerchantNewDTO merchantNewDTO = new MerchantNewDTO();

    merchantNewDTO.setId(Integer.valueOf(merchant.getId()));
    ......

    MerchantConfigurationUtils merchant_config = new MerchantConfigurationUtils();
    Map<MerchantConfigurationFeatureBitString, Boolean> features = merchant_config.initFromDatabaseValue(merchant.getSupported_features());

    merchantNewDTO.setSupports_api(features.get(MerchantConfigurationFeatureBitString.Supports_api));

    return merchantNewDTO;
  }
```

As you can see I want to get `getSupported_features` and to populate the `Supports_api` value.

How I can set these values after Mapping with Lombok?  Is there some way to create an adapter which extends the mapped interface and set/get the values?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57387204/extend-lombok-mapping, seems like you asked the question twice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implement params convert after lombok mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57384982/implement-params-convert-after-lombok-mapping)